# What is this mysterious double dot?

Tags: bash

`grep -R` is returning a file called `..ThisFile`. The double dot is not separated from the filename with a `/`.

I know all about `./` and `../` to signify "this directory" and "the directory above". What does this mean?

```
    $ grep -R fish > grepresults
    $ cat grepresults
    ..SomeFile
```

I looked in, above, and below the current directory for SomeFile, and I sure don't see it. Maybe I messed it.  I don't know what to expect. I don't know what the .. is telling me.

Comment: in addition to uneven_mark's comment, you can list hidden file using ls -a

Comment: I suppose you're right. I was looking for SomeFile and not ..SomeFile. I'll get on this tomorrow morning. Thanks.

Comment: Files can have all kinds of unexpected junk in them, like spaces. Just about the only thing you can't have in a filename is `/`. You can have a file called `*` which leads to all sorts of fun if you try and `rm *` thinking you'll delete just that file.

Comment: Note that SO is only for questions about **writing software**. General questions about how your operating system (or the tools it includes) works are out-of-scope.

Answer (score 2):

It is a normal file. File and directory names are allowed to include dots, also at the beginning. Some tools, like `ls`, do however hide files and directories starting with a dot by default. The `-a` command line flag to `ls` disables this behavior.

Comment: Please do not answer questions that are not about software development as defined in the Help Center. See the "answer well-asked questions" section of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer